# BeautifulSoup to parse an HTML table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is my first time using BeautifulSoup and I am trying to parse an HTML table.  So far, through other examples, I have been able to write some simple code to get very close to what I need.  However, by using the `ele.text.strip()`, I end up losing part of the information that I want to keep.

As seen below, here is what my code looks like now:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("data_table.htm"))

table = soup.find("div", id="CT_Main_1_divResults")
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

data = []
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append(cols)
```

Results:

```
[u'$4,090,000,000',
 u'13.61%',
 u'4,550,000',
 u'100 Grainger Pkwy.',
 u'',
 u'',
 u'']
```

I thought maybe I could just eliminate the `ele.text.strip()` line, and use the same code, as seen below:

```
data = []
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    data.append(cols)
```

Here are the results that provides below:

```
[<td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">$4,090,000,000</span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">13.61%</span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">4,550,000</span></td>,
 <td class=""><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">100 Grainger Pkwy.</span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;"><img src="Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif"/></span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;"><img src="Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/cancel.gif"/></span></td>,
 <td class="tdbrdrright"><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;"><img src="Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif"/></span></td>]
```

**One way around this might be to use the second option and do some fancy string parsing to grab what I need, but I hope theres a better way. In the end, I want the data to look like below.  How can I adjust my code to achieve this?**

```
[u'$4,090,000,000',
 u'13.61%',
 u'4,550,000',
 u'100 Grainger Pkwy.',
 u'Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif',
 u'Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/calcel.gif',
 u'Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif']
```

Comment: post HTML code or url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import bs4

html = '''<td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">$4,090,000,000</span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">13.61%</span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">4,550,000</span></td>,
 <td class=""><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;">100 Grainger Pkwy.</span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;"><img src="Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif"/></span></td>,
 <td><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;"><img src="Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/cancel.gif"/></span></td>,
 <td class="tdbrdrright"><span style="text-align: right; height: 36px;"><img src="Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif"/></span></td>'''
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for td in soup('td'):
    if td.text:
        print(td.text)
    else:
        print(td.img.get('src'))
```

out:

```
$4,090,000,000
13.61%
4,550,000
100 Grainger Pkwy.
Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif
Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/cancel.gif
Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif
```

Change the `print` to `append`, and you will get a list of this output.

The missing info you want is in the `img` tag's attribute, not a text.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try. You'll need to adjust based on what you want to do if there are, say, multiple `img` tags, or text as well as `img` tags, etc., but this should get you started down the right path.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("data-table.html"), 'html.parser')

table = soup.find("div", id="CT_Main_1_divResults")
table_body = table.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

data = []
for row in rows:
    cols = []
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        t = col.text.strip()
        if not t:
            for img in row.find_all('img'):
                t = img.attrs['src']

        cols.append(t)
    data.append(cols)

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[u'$4,090,000,000', u'13.61%', u'4,550,000', u'100 Grainger Pkwy.', u'Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif', u'Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif', u'Inside%20the%20Databases.com_files/True.gif']]
```